# JFreechart I am using a normal distribution. The following error could not be resolved

Tags: operating-system

```
public class JFreechart2 extends ApplicationFrame {
        double mean = 0.0, sd=1.0;
        XYSeries area = new XYSeries("area");
        final XYPlot plot;
        NumberAxis domain;
        XYDifferenceRenderer areaRenderer = new XYDifferenceRenderer();
        Color none = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Color teal = new Color(0, 128, 128, 255);
        XYDataset dataset = initDataset();

        public JFreechart2 (final String title) {
            super(title);

            final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                    "XY Series Demo",
                    "X",
                    "PDF",
                    dataset,
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false
            );

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                shadeArea(10,10, true);
                }
            });

            plot= chart.getXYPlot();
            domain =(NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
            domain.setAutoRangeStickyZero(false); //fix the margin issue with 0
            domain.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(sd)); 

            areaRenderer.setNegativePaint(none); 
            areaRenderer.setSeriesPaint(1, none); // hide the outline of the "difference area"
            areaRenderer.setPositivePaint(teal);
            plot.setRenderer(areaRenderer);
            plot.setDomainAxis(domain);

            final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(chartPanel);

        }

    private XYDataset initDataset() {
            double minX = mean - (4 * sd);
            double maxX = mean + (4 * sd);  // Maximum and Minimnum values on X-axis(4deviations)
            Function2D normal = new NormalDistributionFunction2D(mean, sd);
            XYDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D
            (normal, minX, maxX, 120, "Normal");
            area.clear();
            ((XYSeriesCollection) dataset).addSeries(area);
            return dataset;

    }

    public void clearArea() {
        area.clear();
        }

    public void shadeArea(double x, boolean isInfinity) {
        area.clear();
        if (isInfinity) { //Above infinity
        area.add(x, 0);
        area.add(mean + sd * 4, 0);
        } else { //Below infinity
        area.add(x, 0);
        area.add(mean - sd * 4, 0);
        }

        }

    public void shadeArea(double x1, double x2, boolean isBetween) {
        area.clear();
        if (isBetween) {
        double PDF = dataset.getYValue(0, dataset.getItemCount(0) / 2); //Value that is rounded up to 2 decimal places for the mean PDF value
        area.add(mean - sd * 4.0+0.2, 0);
        area.add(x1, 0);
        area.add(x1, PDF);
        area.add(x2, PDF);
        area.add(x2, 0);
        area.add(mean + sd * 4.0 +0.2, 0);
        } else {
        area.add(x1, 0);
        area.add(x2, 0);
        }
        }


}
```

The code is all...

JFreechart example >>
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartNormalDistributionDemo.htm

If i do it like this, it will come out fine.

However, if I just insert XYSeries and renderer to XYPlot, an error occurs without exception.

The Error is

""Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6""

It comes out like this.

Depending on the number of area.add( x, 0 ),
if there are 3 area.add, 3 errors will occur,
and if there are 4, 4 errors will occur.

---

I'm ashamed to even upload the code, but after holding on to it for 3 days,
I lost my mentality, so I sought help like this.

My code made use of this.
<https://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=117713>

The libraries added are:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoxsI.jpg)

Asking for help...

I'm writing a code that checks how much they overlap up to deviation 2 using two normal distribution functions.

I referred to other codes to not raise the exception, but I couldn't solve it at all.
Perhaps I am guessing that my library is the problem.

Comment: main.java             final JFreechart2 demo = new JFreechart2("Normal Distribution Demo");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);